# Share buttons on mobile site?

Tags: mobile

What are good options (if any) to display share buttons on mobile/responsive sites? Most share buttons seem to open a new window popup or a lightbox like popup. Neither one seems like a  good option.

Comment: Using share buttons on mobile or otherwise is usually bad UX  --  http://worldsmostshareablewebsite.greig.cc/

Answer (score 3):

**Sharing content is a legitimate use case.**  Many sites have gone overboard with the idea, to the detriment of their users, but that still doesn't invalidate the use case.

When sharing buttons were first added (to websites), a button was typically added for each service.  This was fine when there were only a few services, but as the number of sharing buttons increased, more and more screen space (and attention) was being taken up by share buttons.  This presented site owners / managers with a dilemma.  Which buttons should you offer?  The somewhat easy "solution" ,with the "more is better" mentality, was to have a general "share button" which then used an overlay / popup to present a user with every option under the sun.  This was a designer's solution, not a UX solution.

The UX solution is to limit the number of share buttons to those that are key for your users - and this varies from site to site - using the principle that every button you add detracts from the others.  So typically the ideal number of share buttons is around 1-3.

On mobile sites, space is at a premium, and so many schemes are used to try and reduce the space that elements take up.  The obvious carry over from traditional websites was to use a single share button which then let a user pick from a list in either a lightbox or popup.  Assuming the list isn't too large, this is actually a valid interaction design on a mobile as there are a number of functions that are only available on a mobile in this way.  Such as sending to email, or saving to dropbox.  **On a mobile "sharing" actually incorporates more features than social media sharing.**

[image]

The only alternative to a single button and then a list of options is to show all the options on the limited screen real estate, which is generally a poor choice.

I'm not suggesting that every mobile site should have a share button, but assuming it's a needed use case for a site, and assuming there is more than one needed option, a single share button that then presents a user with more options is the best solution I've seen at present.

**TL;DR: If you really need share buttons, and you have more than one, then a general share button which presents the user with the options is still the best alternative.**

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/navigator-share) **native** navigator share api docs.
It is still in **beta, until April 2017**.

Its only available for Chrome 55 and newer.